# Translating an operator (generator of a symmetry) acting on a field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, representation-theory

The representation of Poincare symmetry on fields at the origin, $\Phi(0)$, *induces* a representation of Poincare symmetry on a field at any point $\Phi(x)$.

For Lorentz transformations, we define a matrix representation of the generators $L_{\mu\nu}$ acting on the field at the origin. These are the usual spin matrices $S_{\mu\nu}$:
$$L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(0) = S_{\mu\nu} \Phi(0)$$
where we've suppressed the spin indices. In order to promote this to a representation of $L_{\mu\nu}$ acting on $\Phi(x)$ at *any* spacetime point, we may simply translate the generator $L_{\mu\nu}$ to the point $x$. Here I follow Di Francesco et al., *Conformal Field Theory* equations (4.25) - (4.28).

**My question is** that I am confused by the choice of sign Di Francesco et al. use for their translation.

### What Di Francesco Does

Di Francesco et al. (4.26) quote the translation to be:
$$e^{ix\cdot P} L_{\mu\nu} e^{-ix\cdot P} = S_{\mu\nu} - x_\mu P_\nu + x_\nu P_\mu$$
This follows from the BCH formula, which they state as
$$e^{-A}Be^A = B + [B,A] + \frac{1}{2!}[[B,A],A] + \frac{1}{3!}[[[B,A],A],A] + \cdots$$
This gives the Lorentz representation on $\Phi$, eq (4.28) of Di Francesco et al.:
$$L_{\mu\nu} \Phi(x) = i(x_\mu \partial_\nu - x_\nu\partial_\mu)\Phi(x) + S_{\mu\nu}\Phi(x)$$
I see how these expressions follow from one another, but I am confused with the first step that translates $L_{\mu\nu}$.

### What I would have expected

Instead of (4.26), I would have expected that the "correct" step would have flipped the sign of the translation:
$$e^{-ix\cdot P} L_{\mu\nu} e^{+ix\cdot P} = S_{\mu\nu} + x_\mu P_\nu - x_\nu P_\mu$$
This is because I expect that this comes from:
$$L_{\mu\nu} \Phi(x) = e^{ix\cdot P}\left(e^{-ix\cdot P}L_{\mu\nu} e^{ix\cdot P}\right)\Phi(0)$$
where we have used $\Phi(0) = e^{ix\cdot P} \Phi(0)$. The terms in the parentheses can then be simplified using the BCH formula above. I suspect this is where I have made a conceptual error. The only difference is the sign of $x$ in the finite translations, so that I find:
$$L_{\mu\nu} \Phi(x) = -i(x_\mu \partial_\nu - x_\nu\partial_\mu)\Phi(x) + S_{\mu\nu}\Phi(x)$$
(There is a step where $e^{ix\cdot P}$ commutes past the matrix representation $S_{\mu\nu}$ and the $x_\mu \partial_\nu$ terms.)

### Why this seems sensible to me

The momentum operator is $P_\mu= -i \partial_\mu$ (Di Francesco 4.28), which reflects a choice for the convention of the generators. With this choice,
$$e^{ix\cdot P} \Phi(0) = e^{+x\cdot \partial} \Phi(0) = \Phi(0) + x\cdot\partial \Phi(0) + \cdots = \Phi(x)$$
So it seems to me that my expression
$$L_{\mu\nu} \Phi(x) = e^{ix\cdot P}\left(e^{-ix\cdot P}L_{\mu\nu} e^{ix\cdot P}\right)\Phi(0)$$
should be the correct one.

I wonder if I may have made a mistake with passive versus active transformations?

Comment: this discussion seems very helpful, but shouldnt the transformation property of the field above be $\Phi(x) = e^{ix.P}\Phi(0)e^{-ix.P}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the correct perspective is that the combination $L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(0)$ needs to be translated as follows:
$$L_{\mu\nu}\Phi(0) \to \left(e^{ix\cdot P} L_{\mu\nu} e^{-ix\cdot P}\right) e^{ix\cdot P}\Phi(0)$$
which now correctly matches the notation in Di Francesco.

Comment: Yes, I think this is the correct answer. I am marking it as such. In my original question, the critical error was that I was only translating the field Phi and not the combination L Phi. I welcome any further discussion or corrections on this question.

Comment: This seems to be working, a really good discussion. I guess a good way to think about is that $L_{\mu \nu}$ acts on $\Phi$ and $L_{\mu \nu} \Phi$ should be considered as a field, rather than see how $L_{\mu \nu}$ acts on the operator $\Phi(0)$ or $\Phi(x)$.